# Disable Parallels Plesk Panel admin account

Tags: security, admin, panel, plesk, parallels

In Plesk Panel you have always an Administrator account with the username "admin".

I did not find any setting to change the username to something else than "admin".

I don´t like the idea that someone can try to login with the username "admin" until he find the correct password.

Is it possible to disable the admin account in Plesk or maybe change the name to something different than "admin"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change admin name in Plesk. But you can use "Restrict Administrative Access" or fail2ban "plesk-panel" jail features for avoiding bruteforce attacks on your Plesk Panel.

Answer (score 1):

There is an even better way!

For Linux:  Go to '' /opt/psa/admin/conf '' then name the " panel.ini.sample " - file to panel.ini and insert:

```
[login]
systemAdmin = false
```

Then the root user is deactivated.

Make sure to create a new account before you do that so you don't get locked out :D